# Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code and try to explain it?

Tags: c

Can someone help me because is not looping the question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () 
{
    int counter = 0;
    int average= 0;
    int grade = 0;

    printf("Introduce grade:");
    grade=scanf("%d",&grade);
    counter++;

    while(grade > 0)
    {
        if (grade <0 && grade >100)
            printf("Invalid number");
        else
            average +=grade;
        counter++;
     }

     printf("average = %lf", average/counter);
 }
```

Comment: Why didn't you paste the code here directly?

Comment: its telling me that incorrect and i don't know how to put it right

Comment: You should also indent the code properly. By the way, what is "looping the question"?

Comment: You only call `scanf` once. Outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) /* it is better to add void */

{
    int counter = 0;
    int sum = 0; /* no average is here */
    int grade = 0;
    int check;


    for(;;) /* make it to an infinite loop, break later */

    {
        /* put this block inside the loop */
        printf("Introduce grade:");
        check = scanf("%d",&grade); /* don't assign scanf's return variable to grade, which deletes the grade read */
        if (check != 1) /* check if a integer was read */
        {
            puts("Invalid input. Panik!");
            return 1;
        }
        if (grade <= 0) /* !(grade > 0) */
        {
            break;
        }

        if (grade <0 || grade >100) /* && -> || */
        {
            printf("Invalid number");
        }
        else
        {
            sum += grade;
            counter++; /* made to be done only if grade>=0 && grade<=100 */
        }
    }

    printf("average = %lf", (double)sum/counter); /* add cast to double */

    return 0; /* it may be better to add return 0; */
}
```

Comment: and to add the grade later fro the average , I would use the if statement right?

Comment: Use of if statement isn't wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
grade=scanf("%d",&grade);
```

The above line has some issues. What you are basically doing is reading an input and storing it in `grade`, and then overwriting `grade` with the number of items read. So, you should have the following instead.

```
scanf("%d", &grade)
```

Now, the following also as some issues.

```
if (grade <0 && grade >100)
```

This condition is never true. Instead, you need to use the following.

```
if( grade < 0 || grade > 100 )
```

Finally, your loop never ends. In your loop, you check `while` `grade > 0`. Since you never modify `grade`, the loop will never end. You might add some code in the loop that modifies `grade`.